# How do I use only the code written after the With statement in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am using `With/End With`, and want to only call the code written after the `With` but I can't figure out how to do this. For example:

```
With Activecell.End(xlToRight).End(xlToRight)
    Range(., .End(xlDown)).NumberFormat = "###0"
End With
```

I want the single `.` in this case to represent `Activecell.End(xlToRight).End(xlToRight)` but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: `Range(Active.End(xlToRight).End(xlToRight), Active.End(xlToRight).End(xlToRight).End(xlDown)).NumberFormat = "###0"` should do the trick.  (It's cumbersome, though, which is probably why `With` is being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `Active` was intended to be `ActiveCell`, then the `With ... End With` will be dealing with a single cell. At a minimum, you need to tell `Range` that you want to deal with the `.Cells` (in this case a single cell) that is specified by the `With ... End With` statement.

```
With ActiveCell.End(xlToRight).End(xlToRight)
    Range(.Cells, .Cells.End(xlDown)).NumberFormat = "###0"
End With
```

If this was referring to a range of multiple cells, you should use `.Cells(1, 1)` but since it is by definition a single cell, specifying the position is unnecessary.

Comment: Active is a range object Set = ActiveCell, yes. .cells will work (thanks!) - but is there no way to have only what is after the with statement called? To clarify, this statement works on it's own: Range(Active.End(xlToRight).End(xlToRight), Active.End(xlToRight).End(xlToRight).End(xlDown)).NumberFormat = "###0" But I want to use the With...End With because I have other things I am doing with that cell

Comment: @DyRuss - My best (brief) explanation is that the With ... End With causes the referenced range to lose its default property. Any property acted on within the clause needs to be specified. Without .Cells the referenced range does not know which of its dozens of properties & subproperties you want to act upon.